# Session State Service Failed Suspending Prism Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have an App that use Prism Framework fro MVVM.
I have Two ViewModel class: MainPageViewModel and DetailPageViewModel.
I have an issue when i try to suspend the application in DetailPageViewModel. When i click "suspend" in Visual Studio it throws me an exception "Session State Service Failed".

```
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.SessionStateService.

<SaveAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.MvvmAppBase.<OnSuspending>d__d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```